# Problem with dataset for Cyclistic Bike-Share Case Study

Tags: r, sql-server, csv, import

I am attempting to bulk load 12 `.CSV` files, consolidate them into one `.CSV` file using R, and then load this one file into SQL Server in order to clean and analyze. I manage to generate a consolidated `.CSV` file in R, but when I attempt importing it in MS SQL Server Management Studio the import fails and I get a bunch of error messages I can't make sense of.

Could anyone point me at where I am doing something wrong, please?

Here are my actions in RStudio:

```
### Setting up environment
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("data.table")
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

### Data source - CSV files 2022.06-2023-05 from https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

### Loading and consolidating into a df
raw <- list.files(path = 'C:/edu/Google Data Analytics/Case_study1/s2023l12', full.names = TRUE)
cyclistic23 <- rbindlist(lapply(raw,fread), fill = TRUE)

### Exporting to a CSV file in order to import to MS SQL Server
write.csv(cyclistic23, 'C:/edu/Google Data Analytics/Case_study1/s2023l12/s2023l12.csv', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

All of the above actions seem to work fine and a consolidated CSV file gets generated, but when I attempt to import the resulting CSV file using SQL Server Import and Export Data tool, the file does not get imported and I get a bunch of error messages that I can't make sense of:

```
> Validating (Error) - Messages
>
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "ride_id" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "rideable_type" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "started_at" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
> 
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "ended_at" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "start_station_name" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
> 
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "start_station_id" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "end_station_name" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "end_station_id" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "start_lat" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "start_lng" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "end_lat" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "end_lng" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "member_casual" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 1251) are specified for it.
>  
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - s2023l12" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>  
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
>  
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
```

Comment: Seems like the import job is trying to handle the CSV file data as cp1252 (aka. Latin-1 or ISO-8859-1) but needs to insert it into SQL Server tables whose collations are based on cp1251 (aka. Cyrillic). The OEM characters (those whose octets are >127) are not compatible between [cp1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) and [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) so trying to handle characters in that range will result in loss of information.

Comment: You might be better off with using a `BULK INSERT` statement, if I am honest. You might find you have better controls that using the import wizard (which is a simplified skin for an SSIS package).

Comment: Thank you very much, AlwaysLearning - changing cp1252 to cp1251 in MS import tool helped, but now I am seeing another message which seems to have something to do with one of the columns:
- Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "end_station_name" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Make sure the columns have correct lengths. The "wizard" usually checks first 100 rows or whatever and if values are too short there, it assumes stuff which isn't correct. Go to advanced and make sure OutputColumnWidth is wide enough

Comment: siggemannen, THANK YOU! manually controlling column width worked!